# Accessing multidimensional array in Rails params[]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post

I can't for the life of me figure out how to access the post data in this form naming stucture:

```
feature[0][0], action[0][0]
feature[0][1], action[0][1]

feature[1][0], action[1][0]
```

etc...

I'm trying this, `params['action'][0][0]` but for some crazy reason it just returns `c`. The value of `params['action'][0][0]` doesn't even contain `c`!!

I am completely stuck....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`params['action']` contains the current action (method) name in the controller. If you submit a form, it typically goes to the `create` action and if you ask for `[0]`, you are basically asking for the first letter of the `create` word.

Anyway, I bet your form values are nested under some key. Either send us the form code or add `gem "pry"` to your Gemfile, run `bundle install` and then put `binding.pry` at the top of the `create` action, submit the form and type `params` in the console.

Comment: Ah I didn't realise action was included like that. Many thanks.